# SSIS Package with SharePoint fails when scheduled, but runs fine manually from SSIS Store (SQL 2008)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, sharepoint

I have an SSIS job that gets data from a SharePoint 2010 list that runs perfectly from Visual Studio and also if I trigger it manually from the SSIS store, but not when scheduled as a job in the SQL Server DB Engine instance.

I am doing **everything** using just one super user account called "spadmin".

- It is the account I am using to log into a Windows 7 workstation from which I designed the SSIS package and I tend to run SSMS.
- Is the account used to log into SQL server and have full admin rights to the local server, and to SQL (everything).
- It is also this user's credentials that I am using in the SSIS package to connect to everything I need.
- It is also the account specified to run the scheduled job.

If I connect to the SQL server's SSIS store (**not** the DB engine) via SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and I right click on the job in question that is stored under "Stored Packages\MSDB" and choose to execute it, the job will run without any issues. This happens whether I am using the local SSMS installed on the SQL Server in question, or if I am using a SSMS installation on a remote workstation.

However if I schedule the job through the same SQL's server database engine, the job will fail -- both on a schedule and if I try to run the job manually.

Now here is the puzzling bit: The job will **not** fail if I have **on the background** a remote desktop connection into the SQL server with that super user account (i.e. spadmin) while I run the job. By *on the background* I mean that I am not doing **anything** on this remote desktop connection except login in with the super user account.

When the job fails, I get the following "Bad Gateway" error (see end of post) that suggests the problem is accessing SharePoint. However since I can run this job via the SSIS store with the **same** account for which the job has been scheduled, there is no doubt that this job is capable of running from the SQL Server.

**Server build: 10.50.1617**

I am going mental here. Any ideas of what the problem might be?

Here is the full error message for completeness sake:

> Message Executed as user: MYDOMAIN\spadmin. ...n 10.50.1600.1 for
>   64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.
>   Started:  13:19:34  Error: 2017-01-27 13:19:34.76     Code: 0xC0047062
>   Source: Copy sharepoint list data SharePoint List Source [1]
>   Description: System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The remote server
>   returned an unexpected response: (502) Bad Gateway. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (502)
>   Bad Gateway.     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    Server
>   stack trace:      at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest
>   request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factory,
>   WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)     at
>   Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointUtility.ViewsService.ViewsSoap.GetViewCollection(GetViewCollectionRequest
>   request)     at
>   Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointUtility.ViewsService.ViewsSoapClient.ViewsService_ViewsSoap_GetViewCollection(GetViewCollectionRequest
>   request)     at
>   Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointUtility.ViewsService.ViewsSoapClient.GetViewCollection(String
>   listName)     at
>   Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointUtility.Adapter.ViewsAdapter.GetSharePointListViews(String
>   listName)     at
>   Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointUtility.Adapter.ViewsAdapter.GetViewList(String
>   listName)     at
>   Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointUtility.Adapter.ListsAdapter.LookupViewName(String
>   listName, String viewName)     at
>   Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointUtility.ListServiceUtility.GetFields(Uri
>   sharepointUri, NetworkCredential credentials, String listName, String
>   viewName)     at
>   Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointListAdapters.SharePointListSource.GetAccessibleSharePointColumns(String
>   sharepointUrl, String listName, String viewName)     at
>   Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointListAdapters.SharePointListSource.ValidateSharePointColumns()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointListAdapters.SharePointListSource.Validate()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostValidate(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100
>   wrapper)  End Error  Error: 2017-01-27 13:19:34.76     Code:
>   0xC0047017     Source: Copy sharepoint list data SSIS.Pipeline
>   Description: component "SharePoint List Source" (1) failed validation
>   and returned error code 0x80131501.  End Error  Error: 2017-01-27
>   13:19:34.76     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: Copy sharepoint list data
>   SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more component failed
>   validation.  End Error  Error: 2017-01-27 13:19:34.76     Code:
>   0xC0024107     Source: Copy sharepoint list data      Description:
>   There were errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The
>   package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  S...  The package
>   execution fa...  The step failed.

Comment: Just offhand, you're running a build of SQL Server that's old enough to be in 1st grade, and has been out of official support for a long time. Have you tried looking through service pack kb articles to see if any of them address this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer.

Even though the job was configured to run via a PROXY Account, the SQL Server Agent is still responsible for the job. I had a look and the SQL Server agent was configured to run under the Local System Account on that server. So what I did is to put the agent to run under the superuser admin account and it worked as expected.

Now in this case the fact that the job no longer needs a proxy since the Server Agent itself is running under the ultimate account. However I appreciate that this is not the right way moving forward (even though this isn't my server and I hope I never get to touch it again!) I will be advising the customer to reconfigure SQL so every service runs under a dedicated domain account (i.e. created solely for this purpose), which is the way it should be!

Now what I would love to understand is why the job would run as long as the proxy account used for scheduling the job was logged into the SQL server!